# How to pass async data to child components in an object (Angular6)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

I'm trying to display data retrieved from a server (using Angular 6, Rxjs and Chartjs), and render a chart using the data. 
If I use local mock data, everything renders just fine. But if I use get the data from the servers, the necessary data to render the graphs isn't available so the charts render as blank charts.

Summary: 
A component makes a service call, and prepares an object to pass down to a child component using the response from the service call. However, by the time the response is ready, the object is already sent without the necessary information.

**Service code snippet**:

```
  getAccountsOfClientId(clientID: string): Observable<Account[]> {
    return this.http.get<Account[]>(`${this.BASE_URL}/accounts?client=${clientID}`)
      .pipe(
        tap(accounts => console.log('fetched client\'s accounts')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getAccountsOfClientId', []))
      );
  }
```

**In client-info.component.ts** (component to make the service call, and prepare and pass the object to child component)

```
@Input() client; // received from another component, data is filled

  constructor(private clientAccountService: ClientAccountService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAccountsOfClientId(this.client.id);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateChart(); // render for pie chart
    this.updateBarChart(); // render for bar chart
  }

  getAccountsOfClientId(clientID: string): void {
    this.clientAccountService.getAccountsOfClientId(this.client.id)
      .subscribe(accounts => this.clientAccounts = accounts);
  }

  updateBarChart(updatedOption?: any): void {
    /* unrelated operations above ... */

    // Create new base bar chart object
    this.barChart = {};
    this.barChart.type = 'bar';
    this.setBarChartData();
    this.setBarChartOptions('Account', 'Balance');
  }

  setBarChartData(): void {

    // field declarations..

    console.log('clientAccounts has length: ' + this.clientAccounts.length); // prints 0
    this.clientAccounts.map((account, index) => {
        // do stuff
    });

    dataset = {
      label: 'Balance',
      data: data,
      ...
    };

    datasets.push(dataset);

    // since clientAccounts was empty at the time this function ran, the "dataset" object doesn't contain
    // the necessary information for the chart to render
    this.barChart.data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets
    };
  }
```

I'm looking for changes using ngOnChanges (in the child component), however the chart data is **NOT** updated in the child component after the "clientAccounts" array is filled with the response.

```
@Input() chart: Chart;
@Input() canvasID: string;
@Input() accountBalanceStatus: string;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['accountBalanceStatus'] || changes['chart']) {
    this.renderChart();
  }
}


renderChart(): void {
  const element = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(`#${this.canvasID}`);

  if (element) {
    const context = element.getContext('2d');

    if (this.activeChart !== null) {
      this.activeChart.destroy();
    }

    this.activeChart = new Chart(context, {
      type: this.chart.type,
      data: this.chart.data,
      options: this.chart.options
    });
  } else {
    console.log('*** Not rendering bar chart yet ***');
  }
}
```

Can you point me to how I should continue my research on this?

Sorry for the long question, and thanks!

**EDIT**: Upon request, the templates are below

**Parent (client-info)**:

```
<div class='client-info-container'>
  <div class='info-container'>
    <li>Date of Birth: {{ client.birthday | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'  }}</li>
    <li>Name: {{ client.name }}</li>
    <li>First Name: {{ client.firstname }}</li>
  </div>

  <div class='more-button'>
    <button (click)='openModal()'>More</button>
  </div>

  <div class='chart-container'>
    <div *ngIf='pieChart && client'>
      <app-balance-pie-chart
      [chart]='pieChart' 
      [canvasID]='accountBalancePieChartCanvasID'
      (updateChart)='handlePieChartOnClick($event)'>
      </app-balance-pie-chart>
    </div>

    <div class='bar-chart-container'>
      <div class='checkbox-container'>
        <div *ngFor='let option of cardTypeCheckboxOptions' class='checkbox-item'>
          <input
          type='checkbox' 
          name='cardTypeCheckboxOptions' 
          value='{{option.value}}' 
          [checked]='option.checked'
          [(ngModel)]='option.checked'
          (change)="updateCardTypeCheckboxSelection(option, $event)"/>

          <p>{{ option.name }} {{ option.checked }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf='barChart && client'>
        <!--  *ngIf='client.accounts.length === 0' -->
        <div class="warning-text">This client does not have any accounts.</div>
        <!--  *ngIf='client.accounts.length > 0' -->
        <div>
            <app-balance-account-bar-chart
            [chart]='barChart'
            [canvasID]='accountBarChartCanvasID'
            [accountBalanceStatus]='accountBalanceStatus'>
            </app-balance-account-bar-chart>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**Chart:**

```
<div class='bar-chart-canvas-container' *ngIf='chart'>
  <canvas id='{{canvasID}}' #{{canvasID}}></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your component's HTML as well.

Comment: @FarhanTahir the chart component, or the parent one?

Comment: snippet of parent and chart would be helpful.

Comment: @FarhanTahir Added

Comment: log inside `if (changes['accountBalanceStatus'] || changes['chart']) {  }` and check if you are getting the right data after the asynchronous call is resolved. `ngOnChanges` will usually fire multiple times for each data change.

Comment: @AmitChigadani the changes dont seem to be in the currentValues after the asynchronous call is resolved. I read that it may be because angular change detection checks the differences by looking at the object references, and think it may be related to this. But I'm already re-assigning the object (that is passed to the child component) to an empty object before updating the chart data, so I doubt it's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw that, you are not assigning the data directly to `this.barChart` instead you are assigning it as `this.barChart.data`, which means you are modifying the property directly, which might not invoke the `ngOnChanges` of the child component. This is due to the explanation that you have given in your comments.

> I read that it may be because angular change detection checks the
>   differences by looking at the object references
>
> And it will not get to know when the property of object gets changed

The variable that is bound to `@Input()` property is `this.barChart` and not `this.barChart.data`.

Instead of

```
this.barChart.data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets
};
```

You try this

```
this.barChart = {
    data : {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets
 }};
```

here you are directly modifying `this.barChart` which should trigger `ngOnChanges()`.

EDIT :

You should be invoking `this.updateChart();` inside `subscribe` block of

```
this.clientAccountService.getAccountsOfClientId(this.client.id) 
.subscribe((accounts) => {
   this.clientAccounts = accounts;
   this.updateChart();
})
```

That is why you also have `this.clientAccounts.length` as 0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since this.barChart contains 2 more properties, I believe going with this.barChart = { newproperties: ...} would eliminate previously added fields in the barChart object. I'll try it with the spread operator (such as this.barChart = {...this.barChart, {newproperties}}) and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, make sure you do not loose other properties. You could also use `tempObj` to set the value of some property and then reassign entire `tempObj` to `this.barChart`

Comment: You should be invoking `this.updateChart();` inside subscribe block of `this.clientAccountService.getAccountsOfClientId(this.client.id)
      .subscribe(accounts => this.clientAccounts = accounts)`. That is why you also have `this.clientAccounts.length` as 0

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
>   if (changes['accountBalanceStatus'] || changes['chart']) {
>     this.renderChart();
>   }
> }
> ```

ngOnChanges's argument value is type of [SimpleChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange) for each `Input()`
 prop:

```
class SimpleChange {
  constructor(previousValue: any, currentValue: any, firstChange: boolean)
  previousValue: any
  currentValue: any
  firstChange: boolean
  isFirstChange(): boolean
}
```

You should check you data by `previousValue`, `currentValue`. 
Something like:

```
if(changes.accountBalanceStatus.previousValue != changes.accountBalanceStatus.currentValue 
   || changes.chart.previousValue  != changes.chart.currentValue){
 this.renderChart();
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkuuaj)

Answer (score 1):

Your component needs to have the data before rendering. You may use [resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), a built in feature that Angular provides to handle use-cases like the ones you described.

Also look [here](https://shermandigital.com/blog/wait-for-data-before-rendering-views-in-angular-2/). may be a useful resource in a tutorial form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interact with child components from parent this you nned to use input binding.

**Refer:**

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved and I'd like to share the solution in case anyone needs it in the future. As Amit Chigadani suggested (in the comments), invoking my chart updating functions in the subscribe block worked.

```
getAccountsOfClientId(clientID: string): void {
    this.clientAccountService.getAccountsOfClientId(this.client.id)
      .subscribe(accounts => {
        this.clientAccounts = accounts;
        this.updateChart();
        this.updateBarChart();
      });
}
```